# ajax load checkbox after select combo box - php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that seeks ajax in the neighbourhoods that are registered within a city, this city is chosen and the neighbourhoods it is loaded on a select.
It works perfectly, but I need to put checkboxes so you can be chosen more than one neighbourhood. I'm trying, but it does not work out.
I'm trying to use jQuery plugin [Multiple Selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

```
<head>
    <link href="multiple-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script language="javascript">
function search_data(city)
{
  ajax.open("GET", "search.php?city=" + city, true);
  ajax.onreadystatechange = handleHttpResponse;
  ajax.send(null);
}
function handleHttpResponse()
{
  campo_select = document.form_av.neighborhood;
  if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
    campo_select.options.length = 0;
    results = ajax.responseText.split(",");
    for( i = 0; i < results.length; i++ )
    {
      string = results[i].split( "|" );
      if ( string[0] != "" ){
      campo_select.options[i] = new Option( string[0], string[0] );
      } else {
      campo_select.options[i] = new Option( "all neighborhoods" , "", "defaultSelected","selected" );
      }
    }
  }
}
function getHTTPObject()
{
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else
    if(window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        var prefixes = ["MSXML2", "Microsoft", "MSXML", "MSXML3"]; 
        for(var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++)
        {
             try
            {
             return new ActiveXObject(prefixes[i] + ".XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {}
        }
    }
}
var ajax = getHTTPObject();
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form name="form_av" id="hongkiat-form" method="get" action="">


                    City

                    <select name="city" size="1" class="txtinput" id="city" style="width:130px;" onChange="search_data( this.value )">
                        <option selected value="">Todas</option>
                        <? $consulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM city ORDER BY city_name ASC");
                        while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta)){?>
                        <option value="<? echo retira_acentos($row['city_name']);?>"><? echo retira_acentos($row['city_name']);?></option>
                        <? }?>
                    </select>




                   Neighborhood

                    <select name="neighborhood" size="1" class="txtinput" id="neighborhood" style="width:130px;" multiple="multiple">
                        <option value="" selected>------</option>
                    </select>

               </form>

    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="jquery.multiple.select.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#neighborhood').multipleSelect();
    </script>

</body>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you need checkboxes to do that.
However I think i know what is bugging on your code:
You do a

```
$('#neighborhood').multipleSelect();
```

but when this line is executed, the city is not provided so the multipleselect will be empty. You have to execute the multipleSelect at the end of the search_data function.

hope this will help

Comment: Is it working? if yes, please validate the answer, if not, tell me what s still wrong? :)